# Can anyone help me fix grub rescue?

Tags: grub2

Can any one help me out, Please ?
Showing this message

```
error:file`/boot/grub/i386-PC/normal.mod’not found.
Entering rescue mode…
Grub rescue>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1. Create a [bootable Ubuntu live USB stick](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).
2. Boot the PC from live stick using BIOS settings or setting the primary boot to USB in BIOS.
3. Select *Try Ubuntu* when prompted:

   [image: installer window]
4. Connect to Internet.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and paste the following commands all at once:

   ```
   sudo apt install software-properties-common; \
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"; \
   sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; \
   sudo apt-get update; \
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```
6. You will get the boot repair tool after the process is done.
7. Select *Recommended repair*. It should most likely fix your problem

Comment: You should make it clear that the code lines you posted will install and invoke the third-party [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) software, and also encourage OP to read first an [official Ubuntu description](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) of that software: so that they are prepared to not miss, and to make the right decision on the feature that publishes the repair-attempt's technical details to a pastebin.com post.